# Load JSON (from oracle TIMESTAMP) to Dart DateTime

Tags: json, timestamp, dart, epoch

This is my factory method which takes json from Oracle server. starttime is TIMESTAMP in oracle.

```
factory Status.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> status) =>
new Status(

    status['dataSize'],
    status['statusDescription'],
    status['startTime'],          
    status['server']
);
```

The startime from json is not human readable . How to convert this epoch time to something readable . I tried

```
DateTime.parse(status['startTime']
```

which dint work . How to use

```
DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(startTime)
```

from json.

Comment: What does "The startime from json is not human readable" mean. Where the value comes from is quite meaningless, the relevant information would be how the value looks like.

Comment: The value for startime looks like  1516920700513 .

Answer (score 1):

[**DartPad example**](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/bab006218074687adee1599e09f82af7)

```
new DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(1516920700513);
```

or

```
new DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(status['startTime']),
```